# Wie nennt man den Teil auf der Autotür, wo man den Schlüssel einsteckt

Tags: single-word-request

Wie nennt man den Teil auf der Autotür, wo man den Schlüssel einsteckt?

Ich meine das, was auf dem Foto dargestellt wurde.

[image: http://s1281.photobucket.com/user/thronik/media/klamka%20i%20zamek%20w126/IMG_0035_zpsff940e0a.jpg.html]

Vielen Dank!

Comment: Schloss (evtl. noch beschreiben, z.B.: am Türgriff)

Comment: oder "Türschloss".

Comment: Zum _Türschloss_ gibt es auch den passenden _[Türschlossenteiser](https://www.google.de/search?q=t%C3%BCrschlossenteiser)._

Answer (score 10):

Da es hierzu keinen normierten Begriff gibt, kannst du dies entweder als **Auto-Türschloss** oder **KFZ-Türschloss**, ..., oder auch nur als **Türschloss** bezeichnen.

Answer (score 5):

Dein Bild ist insofern mehrdeutig, als es mehrere verschiedene Teile darstellt. Unter anderem wäre da zum einen das *Schloss* selbst, in welches man den Schlüssel steckt (rund, silbern, Abdeckklappe). Aber im Bild ist auch der *Türgriff* (Plastik, schwarz oder grau), mit dem man die Tür öffnet.

Es kommt also darauf an, ob Du die gesamte Schloss/Griff-Kombination meinst oder nur das einzelne Teil (das Schloss), das mit dem Schlüssel bedient wird.

Answer (score 1):

Neben *Schloss, Türschloss* und seinen Verwandten kann man sich auch auf genau jenen Teil des Schlosses beziehen, in welchen der Schlüssel gesteckt wird. Das wäre der kleine senkrechte Schlitz in der Mitte des (runden) Türschlosses.

Analag zu einer Türklinke an einer Zimmertüre würde ich diese Öffnung *Schlüsselloch* nennen.